# Create Excel pivot table in compact form in SAS

Tags: excel, sas

I'm trying to recreate an Excel pivot table in compact form in SAS. What's the best way to do this?
This is what I want it to look like:

```
                    day1   day2   day3   day4   day5   day6   day7
Facility1
    Imaging
        MRI
        CT
        Angio
        
    Admits
       Inpt Unit 1
       Inpt Unit 2

Facility2
```

I'm not sure which procedure to use. I've only used PROC PRINT and TABULATE sparingly and haven't tried PROC REPORT.

The SAS dataset contains the following fields:

```
   FacilityName
   MetricGrp - Imaging, Admits, etc
   MetricName - MRI, CT, etc
   date 
   MetricValue
   ...
```

with 1 row for each unique combination of the 1st 4 fields.

Comment: What is you want IN the report?  Counts?  Means?  What is the analysis variable?

Comment: I think most would agree a pivot table is already a compact form.  The `day` would have to be the i of the i-th day in a particular facility/metricgroup/metricname?  Where do you want the N of the number of patients? Do you want [ N (list your aggregating functions here) ] ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a simple PROC TABULATE table.

You didn't provide any data so let's look for something everyone has we could use.  Say the first 50 observations of the SASHELP.CARS dataset.  First let's look for some categorical variables.

```
proc freq nlevels data=sashelp.cars(obs=50);
  tables _all_ / noprint;
run;
```

[image]

So let's pick ORIGIN MAKE TYPE and CYLINDERS as the four categorical variables.

So to make a table like your picture cross three of them as the row dimension and then use the fourth for the column dimension.

```
proc tabulate data=sashelp.cars(obs=50);
  class  origin make type cylinders;
  table origin*make*type,cylinders*N ;
run;
```

Result

[image]